# What datatypes translate best between Java and Cassandra?

Tags: java-8, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring Data Cassandra. I am interested in the most painless way to get my project up and working quickly. I am trying to choose appropriate data types so I don't have to think about them going forward.

I have the following data I am creating in Cassandra.

1. lat/long for location - Is BigDecimal the best Java 8 Type for this?
2. thumbnails - 32-64kb of binary data. I wish to store it directly in the record because of it's small size. What's the best Java 8 type for this?
3. timestamp - What's the best Java 8 Class for timestamps on Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, Spring uses Java driver 3.x that is compatible with Java 6, so there are some restrictions in out of box experience. The [driver manual has a table with mapping between Java & CQL data types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping).  Answering to your questions:

1. It depends on your requirement - I think that doubles will be more than enough for that;
2. blobs are by default mapped into `java.nio.ByteBuffer` - if you need, you can add the codec for `byte[]`, but it will require coding on your side (see [doc on custom codecs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/));
3. For mapping between timestamps & Java 8 temporal types, there is a separate jar with so-called [extra codec](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/extras/)s that you can register & get direct mapping into `Instant`, etc.

P.S. Newer driver 4.x supports Java 8 and higher, so you'll get timestamp mapping our of box. But there is no Spring Data version yet with support for this version.